# Assert element in nested array

Tags: java, rest-assured, assertion

Have response from API which is nested array. Want to assert elements in each array with forEach Loop (or any other way, if possible).
Here is response:

```
List<String> titles = response.jsonPath().getList("path_to_List_in_response)
```

And response (part of it, which wants to assert), looks:

```
[[office, desktop, notebok], [office, desktop, notebok], [office, desktop, notebok], [mobile]]
```

Tried following, without success (for first nested array from above):

```
assertThat(partOfResponse.subList(0,1).asList().contains("office")
```

Got, following error:

```
Expecting ArrayList:
[[office, desktop, notebok], [office, desktop, notebok], [office, desktop, notebok], [mobile]


to contain:

["office"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm going to guess that your response contains in the [0,1] position `["office", "desktop","notebook"]` and not `"office"` but you really have not explained enough to be sure.

Comment: If you have a `List<List<String>> list`, and want to assert some `String ex` is in each of the inner lists, then it's a quick `list.stream().allMatch(l -> l.contains(ex))`

Comment: I think he's got a `List<String[]>` though, that's the confusion.

Comment: @markspace Yes, that is correct. Sorry for confusion made. My intention was, actually to assert if first. nested array contains "office", which does, but, obviously did not done it correctly
And if it is possible, wanted to assert each of nested arrays (first 3) contains "office" 
Again, not sure how to do that